UITableView + titleForHeaderInSection + estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = jittery scrolling after rotation
There is a UITableView with 100 sections with headerTitle and 1 cell in each.

Scroll down few cells
Rotate screen
Scroll up – scrolling is jittery and titleForHeaderInSection causes it.

Any idea how to fix it?
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    init() { super.init(style: .insetGrouped) }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: coder) }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: UITableViewCell.description())
        
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 18
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        100
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        "Header"
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: UITableViewCell.description(), for: indexPath)
    }
}


Quick test using your code -- I don't see the "jitter." Can you post a video showing it?


Test project: https://github.com/xapp-dev/TestTableViewScrollWithHeader/tree/main
Test video: https://github.com/xapp-dev/TestTableViewScrollWithHeader/blob/main/TestTableViewScrollWithHeader.MP4
I’m testing tableView with insetGrouped style, if you created Xcode project with storyboard and switched to insetGrouped, Xcode by default sets tableView.sectionHeaderHeight to 18, which needs to be removed.


OK - I see the issue now. It's an odd one... (note that it also happens in landscape). If we scroll slowly, we can see the "jump" exactly when the section header frame comes fully into view. What's even more odd is that the .contentOffset.y does NOT reflect the change! I've tried a few code tweaks, but at this point I have no idea how to get around it :(
